# Object-cache generic locking

Tags: c#, caching

I have a memory cached object-cache, said cache can hold multiple types, and i want to add a lock on said {T} whenever given {T} is accessed.

My implementation:

```
    readonly static IDictionary<Type, List<object>> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<object>>();

    private static List<object> FindTypeInCache(Type type)
    {
        List<object> list;
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(type, out list))
        {
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            _cache[type] = new List<object>();
        }

        return new List<object>();
    }

    public static T FindFirstBy<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        // Is this a valid lock locking only _cache[T] ? And not _cache as whole?
        lock (_cache[typeof(T)])
        {
            return FindTypeInCache(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public static bool AddOrUpdate<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate, T entity) where T : class
    {
        lock (_cache[typeof(T)])
        {
            // Find Type cache.
            List<object> list = FindTypeInCache(typeof(T));

            // Look for old entity.
            var e = list.Cast<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();

            // If no old record exists no problem we treat this as if its a new record.
            if (e != null)
            {
                // Old record found removing it.
                list.Remove(e);
            }

            // Regardless if object existed or not we add it to our Cache.
            list.Add(entity);
            _cache[typeof(T)] = list;
        }
    }
```

Is my implementation correct **only** locking down _cache[T] and not entire _cache as a whole when accessed?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing the code that updates the cache as well - for immutable data, this would be safe, but that would also be true *without* the lock :D Oh, and you're using `ConcurrentDictionary` - that makes your approach somewhat silly; while using a concurrent dictionary, you use manual locking and non-thread-safe code.

Comment: `FindTypeInCache` expects that a type might not currently be in the cache. So why is `FindFirstBy<T>` safe in assuming that `_cache[typeof(T)]` isn't going to throw a `KeyNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of things weird (or outright wrong) with your code.

First, you're using a `ConcurrentDictionary`, but you're not *using it as* a concurrent dictionary. For example, to initialize the list, you'd use the `GetOrAddMethod`:

```
private static List<object> FindTypeInCache(Type type)
{
    return _cache.GetOrAdd(type, () => new List<object>());
}
```

Simple and thread-safe :)

Second, you're locking on `_cache[type]` - but even when there's no such type in the cache. This means a `KeyNotFoundException`.

Third, the only code you're protecting with the lock is the reading. But that quite likely isn't enough - at the very least, you need to also protect the writing with the same lock (especially tricky given the point above), and depending on your actual usage of the return value, the return value's mutations (and if it is indeed mutable, any reads of that mutable value as well).

In other words, you've only managed to protect the code that doesn't actually need protecting (if you use the correct method to update the dictionary)! The extra `lock` around the `Where` etc. might help *slightly*, but it certainly doesn't make the `List` access safe.

All that said, maybe there's a better solution anyway. You're using the cache using generic methods. Why not make the cache itself generic? This way, you'll avoid using a dictionary in the first place, because each of the generic types you're storing in the dictionary will get their own type - it also means you can initialize the `List<T>` in a static constructor safely. Any locking can than also be safely applied to all access to a specific generic cache rather than the "aggregate" cache you have now.

Comment: Maybe the return type should be `IEnumerable` to ensure the cached list is not modified by the caller. But this would be a major change in OP's code.

Comment: @Stefan Well, he doesn't *seem* to be returning the list itself (although he obviously has to modify it somewhere he isn't showing). And `IEnumerable`s will tend to cause exceptions when the underlying collection is modified - you'd have to copy the whole list first anyway. But yeah, there's not enough information to know what he's actually trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my post adding method that "AddOrUpdates" cache.

Comment: @JoachimNordvik Yup, that's quite easy to make safe. Just use `FindTypeInCache` first (the modified version I made), and `lock` on that value. But you still have to synchronize use of the cached value you're working with - the only thing that's safe is the dictionary and list in the cache class, not the value itself. If the cached value is mutable, you're still in trouble :)

Comment: Thanks @Luaan, I will apply your change and change IEnumerable to ConcurrentDictionary. And your right I do need to add code ensuring that given type exist before I lock it down so I can avoid KeyNotFoundException.

Comment: Oh I see what you meant thanks again. Locking at updated method FindTypeInCache(type)